# How to render component based on language

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I have one react native app that supports multiple languages, every language can render some components completely differently. I am just looking for a clean way to do this, is this in any way possible using custom file extensions and adding them to metro.config? I couldn't figure this out.
I will keep the user language in async storage for easy access but I need to somehow be able to decide whether to render Button.en.tsx or Button.es.tsx on runtime.
I also thought of writing up a generic export function for an index.ts, but couldn't really think of a good way to do this.

How can I edit the metro.config in a way that this will work? If that's not possible, is there any other way to do this apart from doing if-checks inside return?

Comment: Look into https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization which should have explanation as how to use it. It should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: This is a library for translation, it has nothing to do with what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with dynamic import, Theoretically with Metro’s segment API. Unfortunately, there's no step-by-step guide available there.

The team at CallStack recently released a new bundler named Re.Pack. It brings the best of Webpack with React Native Specific optimization.

Here is their article on code-splitting and dynamic import with Re.Pack.

https://www.callstack.com/blog/implementing-code-splitting-in-react-native-with-re-pack

Comment: I was actually excited about your suggestion until I saw `Officially, CodePush is only supported if you're not using Code Splitting.` shame, I can't give up codepush. But thank you for the direction

Comment: Despite codePush support limitation. Is the solution helpfully and solve the dynamic import